# Problems with Get-ScheduledJob and Try Catch Finally

Tags: powershell, error-handling, scheduled-tasks

In my PowerShell module, I'm using `Get-ScheduledJob` to list the currently scheduled jobs.

I'll manually delete jobs which ran successfully from the Task Scheduler which causes `Get-ScheduledJob` to throw a non-terminating error saying the job wasn't found and has been removed from the computer.

The weird problem I'm having is trying to wrap this non-terminating error in a `try/catch/finally` block to return a more meaningful error.

The incorrect behavior is the `catch` block runs, but the automatic variable `$_` does not contain the current exception.  As it's null, the `-match` statement returns False.

Am I missing something painfully obvious?

```
function ViewOnly {
  try {
    $try = Get-ScheduledJob -ErrorAction Stop
  } catch {
    $ErrorLine = $_.InvocationInfo.Line
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception
    [void]$ErrorMessage -match '[0-9-_]{13}\s(Server\sReboot)'

    Write-Verbose "Errored at $ErrorLine"

    Write-Warning "The scheduled Job $($Matches[0]) was not found, Run View-ECCReboots to verify servers rebooted"
  } finally {
    $jobs = Get-ScheduledJob

    if ($jobs) {
      $results = foreach ($job in $jobs) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
          Server = $job.Name
          RebootTime = ($job | Get-JobTrigger).At
        }
      }
    } else {
      "No previously scheduled jobs found!"     
    } #end if

    $results | Sort RebootTime | FT -Auto
  } #end finally
} #end viewonly function.
```

Comment: Does [`$Error[0]`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) contain it?

Comment: I just tried that, both `$Error` and `$Error[0]` didn't help.  I forgot to mention this is a script module that contains this and other child functions, if that would be helpful to know.

Comment: Turned out I'm running on lack of sleep, in my testing I was naming the TEST scheduled job TEST and my regex isn't setup for that. Worked as expected using the ACTUAL scheduled job name.